# Posso usar Get ou Post para ler um Array?

Tags: php, html, array

Estou tentando fazer um arquivo .php ler uma array, mas quero também atribuir um id para cada valor no Vetor.

Ess é o html

```
<form method='GET'>
 <input type="hidden" name="idArray[]" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="idArray[]" value="2" />
</form>
```

no php

```
$id1 = $GET[''];
```

é aqui que me perco, pois não sei como colocar o array dentro do GET,
procurei em alguns fórums e testei os modos como foram feitos, mas não obtive sucesso

Comment: Sim, é possível! `echo $_GET['idArray'][0]`; vai precisar de um for para listar todos os valores.

Comment: Basta fazer `$ids = $_GET['idArray'];`. Depois basta um for ou foreach par  mostrar/rprocessar todos.

Answer (score 2):

O jeito mais simples é pegar diretamente pelo nome do *array*:

```
<form method='GET'>
 <input type="hidden" name="idArray[]" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="idArray[]" value="2" />
</form>
```

E no PHP

```
$ids = $_GET['idArray'];
```

Daí é só usar os valores como achar melhor. Por exemplo:

```
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
   echo $id . "<br>\n";
}
```

Ou mesmo como o @rray comentou:

```
$count = count( $ids );   // fora do for, senão o PHP reprocessa a cada iteração.
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
   echo $ids[$i] . "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No formulário:

```
<form method='GET'>
   <?php for($i=1;i<count($array)+1;i++){?>
   <input type="hidden" name="tamanho" value="<?=count($array)?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="array<?=$i?>" value="<?=$i?>" />
   <?php } ?>
</form>
```

No GET:

```
$tamanho = $_GET['tamanho'];

for($i=1;i<$tamanho+1;i++){
   echo $_GET['array'.$i];
}
```

Essa seria a ideia, especifique mais a pergunta e use POST.

Comment: Entendi sua idéia, mas acho que se você colocar o "tamanho" fora do "for" fica melhor. Do jeito que está, vai ter uma entrada "tamanho" para cada item.